# Weblogic 12c JAX-WS deployment with basic Auth

Tags: java, oracle, jax-ws, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I have developed simple web service using Jdeveloper 12c and i want to apply basic Auth to deny anyone who has the link to access the web service methods , below what i have done so far

1. **Web service Code**

   ```
   public class RestClass {

   @WebMethod
   public List<StudentInfoModel> GetStudnetInfo(){

           StudentInfoService st=new StudentInfoService();
           return  (st.getStudnetInfo());


       }
   }
   ```

I have added security constraints to **Web.xml** as follow :

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestClassPort</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>restful.RestClass</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestClassPort</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RestClassPort</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>RestClassPort</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/RestClassPort</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>WSADMINROLE</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>WSADMINROLE</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

then i have mapped security role in **weblogic.xml** as follow

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1256'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>WSADMINROLE</role-name>
        <principal-name>WS_admin</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

and after that I have created new WAR deployment profile and then create EAR deployment profile after i added previous created WAR from EAR assembly section.

Finally, I have deployed the EAR to weblogic, the web service deployed and active, I have added **WSADMINROLE** role and **WS_admin** and map the group to the role. The problem is that I am not able to test the web service, I got the below error:

> Error 403--Forbidden From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol --
>   HTTP/1.1:
>   10.4.4 403 Forbidden

Please note that I have choosed to deploy this Web service under custom roles.

The main purpose of this is to apply basic auth on JAX-WS so
anyone has the link will not be able to execute web service methods.

Comment: Any help on this , i am struggling with this , please anyone has idea comment

Comment: why no one answer this question ?